# Cassandra : Caused by: InvalidRequestException(why:Invalid restrictions)

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, apache-pig

I am very new to cassandra and using 1.2.10. I have a primary key column which is of timestamp datatype. Now I am trying retrieve the data for the date ranges. Since we know we can't use between in cassandra, I am using greater than(<) and less than(>) to get the date ranges. This perfectly seems to work in cassandra's cqlsh. But with pig_cassandra integration, here is the load function.

`cql://<keyspace>/<columnfamily>?where_clause=time1%3E1357054841000590+and+time1%3C1357121822000430"`

And here is the error it throws.

```
2013-12-18 04:32:51,196 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2997: Unable to recreate exception from backed error: java.lang.RuntimeException
    at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlPagingRecordReader$RowIterator.executeQuery(CqlPagingRecordReader.java:651)
    at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlPagingRecordReader$RowIterator.computeNext(CqlPagingRecordReader.java:352)
    at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlPagingRecordReader$RowIterator.computeNext(CqlPagingRecordReader.java:275)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138)
    at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlPagingRecordReader.getProgress(CqlPagingRecordReader.java:181)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigRecordReader.getProgress(PigRecordReader.java:169)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.getProgress(MapTask.java:514)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:539)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.MapContext.nextKeyValue(MapContext.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: InvalidRequestException(why:Invalid restrictions found on time1)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$prepare_cql3_query_result.read(Cassandra.java:39567)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_prepare_cql3_query(Cassandra.java:1625)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.prepare_cql3_query(Cassandra.java:1611)
    at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlPagingRecordReader$RowIterator.prepareQuery(CqlPagingRecordReader.java:591)
    at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlPagingRecordReader$RowIterator.executeQuery(CqlPagingRecordReader.java:621)
    ... 17 more
```

Any help is highly appreciated!!!

Comment: We have found no solution yet. Anyone out there who can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We seem to have fixed the problem by modifying the cassandra source, compiling and then adding the obtained jar file in the lib folder.